# What kind of power cable do I need for the MKR 1010?

Tags: mkr1010

I see very confusing documentation on powering the Arduino MKR 1010. I would like to know what kind of cable to power it with (a weird connector port on its side).

Can I just put 5 V + (AC or DC?) on the Vin port and connect a ground?

Comment: what do you mean by `weird connector`? ... which one are you referring to?

Comment: @jsotola there is only one weird connector on MKR boards :-)

Comment: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/lipo-connector-for-mkr-series-seriously/854713/2

Comment: @Juraj I looked at pictures on the web, and I do not see any "weird" connectors

Comment: @jsotola it is relative. there are two connectors. one is USB, second is some JST. which one of them is the weird one? :-)

Comment: @greg your question is not very clear. Please have a read of [How to ask a good question](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2523/how-to-ask-a-good-question-for-arduino-stack-exchange) and then edit your question to suit.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation shows three ways of powering the board see FAQs section Batteries, [Pins and board LEDs](https://store-usa.arduino.cc/products/arduino-mkr-wifi-1010)

1. Using a USB connector to provide 5V to the board. Typically, this is connected to a USB port on the PC you are using to program the board. Alternatively, a USB cable connected to a standard USB power supply could be used after the program has been loaded.
2. Using the Vin pin to supply a REGULATED 5V (maximum 6V). Of course, this is DC. Yes, you would also connect the power supply GND to the board's GND pin.
3. LiPo battery. This is a little more complicated to use safely and there is documentation on that as well - see the [app note here](https://docs.arduino.cc/tutorials/mkr-wifi-1010/mkr-battery-app-note) to start. You **absolutely** need to understand how to use a battery with that board - there are safety concerns in this regard that can't be ignored.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much DrG. I am very new to Arduino.. There is no USB port( unless that is the small type "C"? connector on the end). I see the Vin pin and thanks to your " app note" insert I found what I need, a 2-pin JST-PH connector for the battery, now to look for it.

Comment: found a proper USB connector, on my wifes Kindle. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Just if you are wondering,The mkr1010 uses Micro USB (USB-B) arduino doc says. https://docs.arduino.cc/hardware/mkr-wifi-1010

Comment: that is not the weird connector

Comment: Then is it  this Battery connector: The connector is of type JST S2B-PH-SM4-TB(LF)(SN). Mating connector is JST PHR-2?

Comment: This maybe? Additional I2C Port

The MKR WiFi 1010 has an additional connector meant as an extension of the I2C bus. It's a small form factor 5-pin connector with 1.0 mm pitch. The mechanical details of the connector can be found in the connector's datasheet.

The I2C port, also referred to as the Eslov self-identification port within Arduino, comes with: SDA, SCL, GND, +5V, and an extra digital pin meant to send an alarm to the otherwise plain I2C devices connected to it. The pinout is shown in the following image: